# Convert encoded characters to string in Rust/Actix-Web

Tags: rust, actix-web

Using `actix-web`'s `web::Bytes`, I can get the payload from a form submission. It is a simple form with one input named `username` and another input named `text`. The raw bytes stream looks like this

```
b"username=User&text=%22Hello%2C+World%21%22"
```

The content in the text submitted is simply `"Hello, World!"`.

Without using `serde`, what methods can I use to convert the above `%22Hello%2C+World%21%22` into the intended string `"Hello, World!"`?

Comment: https://docs.rs/urlencoding/latest/urlencoding/

Answer (score 2):

Your data is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. you can use a crate like [form-urlencoded](https://docs.rs/form_urlencoded/latest/form_urlencoded/) to parse it.

Example:

```rust
let x = form_urlencoded::parse("%23first=%25try%25");
println!("{:?}", x); // [("#first", "%try%")]
```